# Is there a list of good kanban books?

Tags: kanban

Looking for something that provides a good introduction into the topic as well as how to introduce it to an organization and how to apply it.

Comment: Closing as "Too Localized" since the list of books would change over time. Also, this is "Not Constructive" since the answers are mostly just a list of things, which isn't a good fit for Stack Exchange. See [Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Answer (score 8):

There are two canonical books on Kanban:

1. David Anderson's [Kanban, Successful Evolutionary Change for Your Technology Business](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0984521402)
2. Henrik Kinberg's and Mattias Skarin's [Kanban and Scrum - making the most of both](http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/kanban-scrum-minibook)
3. (updated) Henrik Kniberg's [Lean from the Trenches](http://pragprog.com/book/hklean/lean-from-the-trenches) is great both at describing how to scale Kanban up but also as a practical guide to Kanban implementation.

You can also find answers to [this question](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/1847/scrum-agile-kanban-looking-for-for-dummies-type-of-information) useful although it is definitely broader. One of sources which is definitely worth recommending is [Limited WIP Society site](http://www.limitedwipsociety.org/).

There is also a great set of resources on [Lean-Kanban University site](https://www.kanban.university/#resources).

Answer (score 3):

[image]

[**Custom Kanban - Designing the System to Meet the Needs of Your Environment**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1563273454)

by   Raymond S. Louis    ISBN:  9781563273452

Productivity Press   Copyright Replenishment Technology Group, Inc. ©  2006 (254  pages)
Designed to help you develop and implement a correct and successful kanban system for your company, this compelling book explains appropriate kanban techniques based on specific environmental factors and company needs.

[image]

[**Kanban made simple - Demystifying and Applying Toyota's Legendary Manufacturing Process**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0814407633)

by   John M. Gross  and  Kenneth R. McInnis    ISBN:  9780814407639

AMACOM   Copyright John M. Gross and Kenneth R. McInnis ©  2003 (259  pages)
Using Toyota as an example, this is a step-by-step guide to incorporating the ingenuity of the kanban system into any manufacturing environment.

Answer (score 3):

If you've got a Kindle, I wrote one which is designed as a first stop introduction to Kanban and priced it at the lowest point Amazon allows, $1.

If you want to really understand Kanban, read David's book. For a better introduction to the theory of lean software development, read Mary and Tom's book from 2003, "Lean Software Development."

Comment: Maybe a link to your ebook would be nice?

Answer (score 2):

This is one of my favorite "getting" started guides: http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/kanban-scrum-minibook

Note, that it also touches on SCRUM as well.

I came across this list last night, and thought I would update this thread. I have read through some of them and it seems to be a fairly comprehensive list: http://www.targetprocess.com/blog/2009/05/lean-and-kanban-software-development.html

Answer (score 1):

All great answers above.  I believe David Anderson will be releasing a version II of his book over the next year or so.  After reading the Anderson's book and or Kniberg/Skarin's book, you should really follow the kanbandev yahoo group for the most current information.

I would also suggest subscribing to [David's blog](http://agilemanagement.net)

This video is also a good resource to share with people who don't know much about Kanban but have worked in a Scrum environment.

[Scrum applied to Kanban](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0EIMxyFw9T8)