# Swimlane, category or new project for grouping dependent projects in Kanboard

Tags: kanban, multi-projects, kanban-board

We have just recently started to use Kanboard, but still not sure how to apply our projects in the Kanboard system. We have a couple of major software projects contains sub-projects such as Delphi components, Lazarus components, Windows version, Linux version, Innosetup maker, documentation, etc.
We would like to know how to initially create the structure of the projects/swimlanes/categories in the Kanboard to start using it.
Could anyone explain the usage of and the difference between swimlane and category in Kanboard?
How should we fit the mentioned sub-projects in a project, swimlane or category?

Comment: [I don't know, experiment.](http://brodzinski.com/2009/12/kanban-story-experiment.html) Also, do you mean 'Kanban'?

Comment: Kanboard is the tool using Kanban. https://kanboard.net

Comment: Sounds to me like you've heard someone down 't pub talking about this new "Agile" thing, that will fix lots of issues. So you've decided you want to implement it at work. Take a step back. Get a solid understanding of Agile, then how Kanban fits into that, and pilot it to see if it works. The fact someone has decided to use it across all the projects you've listed above but doesn't know how Kanban works shows you're biting off more than you can chew. Buy a bunch of books, read them, understand agile, before implementing it. TBH, in the nicest way possible, this question scares me a bit! :)

Comment: As the question stands, it seems an XY problem. Having that said, wouldn't it be the case to close this question and suggest the OP to go through https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/3305/what-is-kanban?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you make separate boards for the independent projects unless the same team is working on all the parts simultaneously, which doesn't make much sense to me based on your short post. If you are using the same board, then color code the different parts. If you are using an electronic board, then you can use tags or labels.

Your swim-lanes must not represent components but your progress towards output of value. Its all about staying lean and mean when using Kanban and minimizing waste, which includes spending a lot of time writing the requirements and categorizing them. Instead, let your Product Owner (Service Request Manager) move things between the swim-lanes based on the business needs and priorities.

Your swim lanes could be something like:

Ideas | Ready for Development | In Progress | In Test | In Staging | In Production

In any case, it sounds to me that there is a signifiant misunderstanding of Agile and Kanban so I strongly recommend you spend more time reading or hire a qualified coach. Kanban isn't something you switch on and get results. You don't need a "Kanban Board" to be agile or to follow Kanban. I would argue they can do more harm than good for new teams.

Moving to agile is tough, especially since many educational institutes around world talk about SDLC and Waterfall when they discuss project management. Agile is a completely different paradigm, almost an opposite paradigm, to the traditional prescriptive paradigm of software development.

Good luck.